# Print the value corresponding to specific rowname from a matrix

Tags: r

I just have a simple R question. I have a matrix with rownames A,B,C,D

```
    Values
A      4     
B      5
C     10
D     21
```

I just want to print or view the value corresponding to specific rowname.
Example - The value for rowname B (which is 5)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply subset by row and column name.

```
m["B", "Values"]
# [1] 5
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(c(4L, 5L, 10L, 21L), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "Values"))
```